# Angular 7 Drag n drop in grid not able to move panels between grid

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-cdk

I am trying out Angular 7 Drag n Drop with a bootstrap grid.

Inside the grid I have panels.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">

   <div class="col-md-4" cdkDropList>
      <div class="panel panel-primary" cdkDrag>
         <div class="panel-body">
            one
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-4" cdkDropList>
      <div class="panel panel-primary" cdkDrag>
         <div class="panel-body">
            two
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-4" cdkDropList>
      <div class="panel panel-primary" cdkDrag>
         <div class="panel-body">
            two
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to move the panels around and maybe sort them and drop the panel in empty grid cells.

My problem is that these panels are stack inside the assigned parent div's and I cannot swap them

How can I get it so I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Angular CDK Drag & Drop is based on moving item in array. And that's what you don't do in your example.
To make this working in a way you described. You should follow these steps.

**First step:**

As a first step you should create a `@ViewChild` which will get all those `cdkDropLists`. Array which will contain your `panels`. The last one will be property `listsChecked`.

```
@ViewChildren('list') lists: QueryList<CdkDropList>;
listArray = [[{col: 4, text: 'one'}], [{col: 4, text: 'two'}], [{col: 4, text: 'two'}]];
private listsChecked: boolean = false;
```

**Second step:**

Let's change the `HTML` template, so it will loop through array you created in a first step. So the `HTML` will look like this.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let listItem of listArray; let i = index">
        <div class="list col-md-4">
          <div class="list-item panel panel-primary" *ngFor="let item of listItem">
            <div class="panel-body">
              {{item.text}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Third step:**

To be able to drag and drop update the `HTML` template from step 2. Firstly you should add `cdkDropListGroup` to `.row`. Next add `[cdkDropListData]="listItem"` to the `<div class="col-md-4"></div>`, to the same element add also this `cdkDropList #list="cdkDropList"` this is used for the `@ViewChild()` from step 1, again to the same element add `(cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"` this will call a method always when you drop an item. Also add a cdkDdrag to `.panel .panel-primary`. The template should then look like this

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row" cdkDropListGroup>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let listItem of listArray; let i = index">
        <div class="list col-md-4" [cdkDropListData]="listItem" cdkDropList #list="cdkDropList"
             (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
          <div class="list-item panel panel-primary" *ngFor="let item of listItem" cdkDrag>
            <div class="panel-body">
              {{item.text}}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Fourth step:**

To your `*.component.ts` add AfterViewChecked to implements. Into `ngAfterViewChecked()` add this code

```
 ngAfterViewChecked() {
     if (this.lists.toArray().length > 0 && this.listsChecked === false) {
      this.listsChecked = true;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.lists.length; i++) {
        const array = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < this.lists.length; j++) {
          if(i !== j) {
            array.push(this.lists.toArray()[j]);
          }
        }
        this.lists.toArray()[i].connectedTo = array;
      }
    }
 }
```

This code will go through all elements with `#list` in you template and add every `cdkDropList`except him self to `cdkDropconnectedTo` <- this is connecting more lists between each other. And add a `drop()` method.

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
     if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex);
    }
 }
```

This will check if the destination is is same as a previous container and move as necessary. The `drop()` I got from [Angular Drag & Drop documentation](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview)

Everything should be working the containers will still exists as empty col's. I 
hope it will help you.